# Access to a parameter in another class

Tags: vba, oop

Hi friends I have a class in vba, in which I have defined a parameter like this:

```
Public lcl As Boolean
```

At the first I am setting this parameter in this block:

```
If MsgBox("Lokal ?", vbYesNo, conConnectMsg) = vbYes Then
         strTmp = CurrentDb.name
         lcl = True
      Else
       strTmp = pconDatenVerzeichnisStandard & Me.DataMDB
         lcl = False
      End If
```

I want to have access to this parameter from a From, but this boolean Parameter `lcl` is always false. Is my code correct? What is the problem in my code, which `lcl` is always false

Comment: The code seems ok but did you check the value after you `If Else` (via `Debug.print` or whatever) to be sure `lcl` is `True` if yoy click Yes?

Comment: I can see the right value for `lcl` in the class, but in another one, it is always `False`

Comment: What I don't really get is: what is `lcl` supposed to be? A global variable (even if it's generally bad)?

Comment: Yes, it is a global variable. What should I use instead of global variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check this link:
[Class Modules vs. Standard Modules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240811%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

I'm not really used to OOP iv VBA but I think if you declare a variable like that in a module, it will be Global, **but** in a class it will be a property that you'll have to access like that:

```
 yourClassInstance.lcl    ' Because it is public
```

(If `private`: use `Let`/`Get` ... [Classes in VBA](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx))

Anyway, I was just saying that you have to be carefull when using global variables (Last link: [Global variables](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) even if it's manly about c)

But the point is: you'll have to use a instance of your object to access `lcl`

Last point: If not already done, add `Option Explicit` at the top of you modules/classes because it could help in a case like that ... if you don't, if you use `lcl` somewhere it doesn't exist yet VBA will create it, it may be what happened (It's using a **local** `lcl`)

Hope this will help a little, I don't have enough code here to understand what exactly happens.